# Flutter Formz: The getter 'isSubmissionFailure' isn't defined for the type 'FormzStatus'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I cannot access the FormzStatus status in the `BlocBuilder` or the `BlocListener`. Below is what my state and my BlocBuilder look like:

`State`:

```dart
class SignupState extends Equatable {
  const SignupState({
    this.status = FormzStatus.pure,
    this.firstName = const FirstNameField.pure(),
    this.lastName = const LastNameField.pure(),
    this.email = const EmailField.pure(),
    this.phoneNumber = const PhoneNumberField.pure(),
    this.password = const PasswordField.pure(),
    this.confirmPassword = const ConfirmPasswordField.pure(),
    this.userType = const UserTypeField.pure(),
    this.error = '',
  });

  final FormzStatus status;
  final FirstNameField firstName;
  final LastNameField lastName;
  final EmailField email;
  final PhoneNumberField phoneNumber;
  final PasswordField password;
  final ConfirmPasswordField confirmPassword;
  final UserTypeField userType;
  final String error;

  ...
}
```

`BlocListener`:

```dart
...
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.read<SignupBloc>().add(
          UserTypeChanged(userType),
        );
    return BlocListener<SignupBloc, SignupState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state.status.isSubmissionFailure) // error is here {
          
        }
      },
  ...
```

Comment: The FormzStatus is an enum (see https://pub.dev/documentation/formz/latest/formz/FormzStatus.html) with the `submissionFailure` value. The correct way to check your status variable is the following:

    ...
    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         context.read<SignupBloc>().add(
          UserTypeChanged(userType),
        );
        return BlocListener<SignupBloc, SignupState>(
           listener: (context, state) {
              if (state.status == FormzStatus.submissionFailure) {
          
           }
         },
    ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the value or the enums.
Change the error line to:

```
 if (state.status == FormzStatus.isSubmissionFailure) {
```